# Sprite hitting an invisible platform

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hi there I'm currently making a platform game and I'm having trouble where the sprite starts at the very bottom of the stage:
Like this:

[image]

and if I try to jump, it stays on an invisible platform:

[image]

Here's my external code so far :

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.*;

public class codes extends MovieClip
{
    public function codes(){
        chara.stop();
        stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);
        stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyup);
        stage.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);
    }
    var mspeed:Number=0;
    var sy:Number=2;
    var gv:Number=1;
    var jumped:Boolean=false; 

    function keydown (e:KeyboardEvent){
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.LEFT){
            mspeed=-10;
            chara.gotoAndStop(2);
        }
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.RIGHT){
            mspeed=10;
            chara.gotoAndStop(1);
        }
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.SPACE) {
            if (!jumped){
                sy=-20;
                jumped=true;
            }
        }
    }

    function keyup (e:KeyboardEvent){
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.LEFT){
            mspeed=-0;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.RIGHT){
            mspeed=0;
        }
    }

    function gameloop (e:Event) {
        chara.x += mspeed;

        if (chara.x<0) {
            chara.x=0;
        }
        if (chara.x>950) {
            chara.x=950;
        }

        sy+=gv;
        if (!jump.hitTestPoint(chara.x,chara.y,true)) {
            chara.y+=sy;
        }

        for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
            if (jump.hitTestPoint (chara.x, chara.y, true)) {
                chara.y--;
                sy=0;
                jumped=false;
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: There's a nice step-by-step tutorial about platformers in AS3 (there are plenty others, just Google > AS3 platformer tutorial): http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/advanced/how-to-create-a-platform-game-in-as3-part-1/

Comment: Hello thank you for replying! I'm already using a tutorial and now I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong

Comment: It looks like he is standing on the platform with his face! Are you sure that's not what's happening?

Comment: @NealDavis OH GOSH I just tested the code and the character IS standing with his face. What would cause this bug?

Comment: It's not bug. It's doing what you told it to. It may be as simple as making sure that the character has his feet at the origin point of the movie clip (the little white dot when you edit the movie clip)

Comment: @NealDavis THANK YOU! Now it works like I intended!

Comment: Alright cool. Just upvote the comment that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks like he is standing on the platform with his face! Are you sure that's not what's happening?

---

> It's not bug. It's doing what you told it to. It may be as simple as making sure that the character has his feet at the origin point of the movie clip (the little white dot when you edit the movie clip)